# How to connect to a cluster of sentinels using StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis, sentinel

Does `Stackexchange.Redis (C#)` support connecting to a cluster of sentinels for high availability with the latest version ? I'm finding it a bit odd how such an important feature of `redis` is not properly documented or practically no examples at all. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com.
Please take some time to read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and
["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).
Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 0):

You can see how to connect to sentinels by examining the tests of StackExchange.Redis. Specifically this one https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/tests/StackExchange.Redis.Tests/Sentinel.cs

Essentially the code you need to look at is here:

```
   public Sentinel(ITestOutputHelper output) : base(output)
    {
        ConnectionLog = new StringWriter();

        Skip.IfNoConfig(nameof(TestConfig.Config.SentinelServer), TestConfig.Current.SentinelServer);
        Skip.IfNoConfig(nameof(TestConfig.Config.SentinelSeviceName), TestConfig.Current.SentinelSeviceName);

        var options = new ConfigurationOptions()
        {
            CommandMap = CommandMap.Sentinel,
            EndPoints = { { TestConfig.Current.SentinelServer, TestConfig.Current.SentinelPort } },
            AllowAdmin = true,
            TieBreaker = "",
            ServiceName = TestConfig.Current.SentinelSeviceName,
            SyncTimeout = 5000
        };
        Conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options, ConnectionLog);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Assert.True(Conn.IsConnected);
        Server = Conn.GetServer(TestConfig.Current.SentinelServer, TestConfig.Current.SentinelPort);
    }
```

And then here:

```
   [Fact]
    public void SentinelGetMasterAddressByNameTest()
    {
        var endpoint = Server.SentinelGetMasterAddressByName(ServiceName);
        Assert.NotNull(endpoint);
        var ipEndPoint = endpoint as IPEndPoint;
        Assert.NotNull(ipEndPoint);
        Log("{0}:{1}", ipEndPoint.Address, ipEndPoint.Port);
    }
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)